# Rewrite URL condition - Change particular string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What's the best way to rewrite URLs as 301 redirects with the following conditions?

Sample old URLs to rewrite:

```
/category/subcategoryA/somethingDifferent
```

New URLs should be:

```
/category/subcategoryB/somethingDifferent
/category/subcategoryA/somethingDifferentAgain
```

**Note:** System is Joomla if there is a better way for it then mod_rewrite please tell me

Edit: 
First I'm sorry I worded my request so poorly.
The URL rewrite is to rename the "subcategoryA" part of the URL.
I want to redirect to the same articles after I moved them from one category to the other.

Example:

```
/category/oldsubcategory/article-slug-here
```

Should redirect to:

```
/category/subcategoryA/article-slug-here/
```

Comment: You give _one_ example input URL, and then _two_ different desired results - what sense it that supposed to make?

Comment: I add an edit - I'm sorry my request wasn't clear enough and I hope you take a look at it again

Answer (score 1):

You can use this redirect rule at top of other Joomla rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([\w-]+)/oldsubcategory/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/subcategoryA/%2 [L,NE,R=301]

# your existing Joomra code
```